# Question migrated from ServerFault to SuperUser?

Tags: discussion, support

Firstly, I want to ask people not to interpret this as offensive: I'm not trying to be. This shouldn't be. But, I would like dicuss a migration and one user in specific.

Why was [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/144818/can-the-guest-user-login-via-rdp-in-windows-xp) migrated from ServerFault to SuperUser? It is a question about configuring remote-desktop for a headless virtual machine? How much more server-y do you need? The configuration of a daemon's ACL on Windows is SuperUser material? Seriously now.

What about the other questions pertaining to rdp, and "remote desktop" on ServerFault:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rdp
- https://serverfault.com/search?q=remote+desktop

The reason is

> This question is related to computer hardware or computer software in general, and is a better fit for Super User.

But, I simply don't believe that this question is general.

An alternate explanation follows: I think this might just be the personal prejudice by [@Squillman](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/75852/squillman): "Face it, people are starting to ignore your drabble [sic]. But apparently not quite enough to keep you at 1 rep." This seems awkward given my dandy reputation on the [other](https://serverfault.com/users/18822/evan-carroll) [trilogy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124486/evan-carroll) [sites](https://superuser.com/users/11116/evan-carroll). Is it possible that we can defrock him for this and set him back to a modest level of exp so he can't continue to wreck havoc on the system?

Thanks.

Comment: You should have quit while you were ahead. This was a good question up until that last paragraph, which, while it might have a point, is still phrased in an inflammatory way.

Comment: @mmyers: I've tried to cool off that last graf a bit without completely excising it. Probably should have just stricken it out, but that really wasn't viable since that's an important part of Evan's question here.

Comment: @Evan If migrations, editing, closings bother you in any way, then I think perhaps SO/SU/SF/M is not for you. I don't mean to be rude or offensive, but truly, SO/SU/SF/M is all about Close/Edit/Migrate . See other questions like "Is it okay for other people to edit my posts?" "Is microediting okay", etc.

Comment: @Zom: Yeah, I took it out and then thought better of it.

Comment: What [about](http://serverfault.com/faq) *Server Fault is for system administrators and IT professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity. If you are in charge of servers/networks/many desktop PCs (other than your own) then you're in the right place to ask your question!  Well, as long as the question is about your servers, your networks, or desktops you support, anyway.*

Comment: @Arjan: that's official documentation, which is here anyway superseded by official prejudice.

Comment: *Official prejudice*? Sigh.

Comment: @Evan: i honestly don't see any prejudice here.  if you need steps to do it on one desktop, it tends to go to SU.  if you need steps to do it on many desktops at once (eg, GPO), it tends to go to SF.  your question as written falls into the one-desktop category.

Comment: @Evan I think it should be noted that while the author of the comment you object to did cast one close vote, it was a mod performed the migration. I think one can reasonably argue that no one knows better than the mods what questions do not belong on their sites.

Comment: @Evan,  Close/Edit/Migrate is only the tip of "The Trilogy Iceberg of Things That May Irritate You". If it REALLY bothers you, as you continue on with SO/SU/SF/M you are only going to find worse irritations. Take for example this recent event : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602555/get-mechanize-to-handle-cookies-from-an-arbitrary-post-to-log-into-a-website-pro . I'm a customer of TMobile and thought the question nefarious. I got hateful comments and a nice fat negative rep for complaining about it on Meta. My point, after you get past Close/Edit/Migrate the irritations only get worse.

Comment: @Evan taking into consideration your steep negative rep chart, you might want to ask yourself if SO/SU/SF/M is doing your mental health any disservice. >_< I mean no offense, only concern for your well-being. I don't want to see anyone die here like it's WoW because they are too addicted to eat/sleep/potty.

Comment: @Evan unrelated, have you seen this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying

Comment: @rlb.usa: He's only a part-time troll. Don't worry too much.

Comment: @mmyers @zombie I'm tempted to roll it back to the original post...

Comment: @squillman: That'd be up to you; I wouldn't get in an edit war with you over it.

Comment: Rolled back to maintain original context.  @Zombie: thanks for the thought, though!

Comment: I agree with the rollback @squillman, now I can give this post the downvote it deserves. I read it before and thought, "Wow, this is too well put for me to downvote", but now I realize that's because I was reading @Zombie Nixon's edits, HA!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right on this one, that should have been left on ServerFault.

That's the kind of question I would ask for Servers that I administrate (since I don't have a lot of RDT experience).

Answer (score 7):

I believe this was correctly migrated -- you're asking about Windows XP.  That is, the OS that is serving the remote desktop is a desktop OS, not a server OS.

It is something that server admins should be aware of, so there's no real reason it *can't* be left on Server Fault, but I think Super User is the correct place to put this.  If you asked the same question about Windows Server 20XX, or if you'd asked about enabling this functionality via a domain's Group Policy, then Server Fault would be the more appropriate site.

You asked a gray-area question without a lot of detail and the Server Fault community decided to migrate it.  I don't see any particular malice here, though that's no guarantee it doesn't exist.  I'm sorry if it does.

**If you think it truly belongs on Server Fault**, then I recommend editing the question to provide more details that will make it more of an appropriate SF question, and flagging a moderator to see about getting it reopened.  If you're done with the question (you seem to have found your own answer), just let it be.  As it stands it is perfectly appropriate on Super User.

Comment: For topics like this in a grey area, I think what matters is simply where it will get the most answers. If such a question is asked on SU and doesn't get answers after some time, migrating it to SF is a good idea, and same in the opposite direction.

Comment: If it's someone else's Windows machine, as is suggested by the fact that he's worried about the guest user, then it's on topic for Serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

Call it personal prejudice if you want.  It's not.  I would have voted to close that question regardless of who asked it.  The question is related to a specific, single machine that is not  a server OS.  I also voted to close [**your other one**](https://serverfault.com/questions/144782/virtualbox-serial-port-limit-of-two) on the same grounds, but you'll also notice that I even answered it for you.

Here's the aforementioned "drabble" comment [**in full context**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49852/what-will-you-do-with-your-questions-problems-if-there-is-no-stackoverflow/49889#49889).

If you feel that I am out to get you, I humbly invite you to flag for moderator attention or send a message to the team.  I also invite you to review the content of your posts on meta.  It could be argued that you have the same complaint against high-rep users and diamond mods on trilogy sites as you allege I have against you.  But maybe that's just me...

Answer (score 1):

You found the answer to your own question. So being migrated didn't affect your ability to get an answer. Even so, being migrated leaves a trail on ServerFault, so you get *more* attention being migrated, that is, people can see the question on two sites rather than one...

I think @quack quixote provided the best explanation of why this question was a gray area and was migrated. I think that the migration was probably fine, it hasn't caused any specific harm being migrated.